# php файл как динамический js

Tags: php, javascript

Можно ли делать так, если нет других вариантов.

```
<script src="/file.php?param" ><script>
```

Или так

```
<script src="/?param" ><script>
```

Понятное дело что по этому запросу будет отдаваться js.

Дело в том что js файл генерится динамически. С каждым запросом файл меняется. Некоторые переменные в js файле получают значения из php.

Раньше генерил js и вставлять прямо в html. 
Но тут прикрутили кеширование. все страници кешируются на 30 минут. Все страници стали статическими.

Comment: Можно так сделать. В чем сложность попробовать самому?

Comment: Да я пробовал. Я в смысле "запаха" кода.

Comment: Если задача требует, то в чем проблема. Я так даже для <img src="file.php"> делал, чтобы куки вешать с помощью загрузки картинки.

Comment: в первый раз вижу чтобы с помошью пхп пишут js. Это как минимум не правиль я думаю

Comment: @user8978194 это вполне нормально